# Understanding the conditions of subspaces and how to prove them

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\mathcal M_{n\times n}$ be the vector space of all real matrices of size $n\times n$.

I want to prove (or disprove) that the set of $n\times n$ matrices with $\det(A)=1$ is a subspace of $\mathcal M_{n\times n}$. So the set is $S=\{A\in \mathcal M_{n\times n}:\det A=1\}$
and if I'm correct, I need to prove 3 things:

**(1) Contains origin**
**(2) Closed under addition**
**(3) Closed under multiplication**

**(1):** My initial thought is that no matrix in $S$ can satisfy **(1)** since no matrix contains the origin that has a determinant of $1$? I don't fully understand what it means to contain the $0$ vector/origin/is non-empty?

**(2):** Assuming **(1)** *is* satisfied (again, I don't know), I'd consider whether this is closed under addition which I also think is unsatisfied by matrices $A,B\in S$ since \begin{align*}
A&=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} & B &= \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
are both in $S$ but their sum doesn't have a determinant of $1$.

**(3):** Assuming **(1) and (2)** *are* satisfied, I belive this is closed under multiplication since $\det(A)\det(B)=\det(AB)$ right? I've continued my consideration of each condition because I want to show my whole thought process so I can be corrected where I go wrong. I'm in need of direction on problems like these, and I especially don't understand the **(1)** condition in proving subspaces.
**Side note:** I'm very open to tips on how to prove anything in math, proofs are new to me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "subspace"? Are you thinking of $\mathcal{M}_{n \times n}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and so by "subspace" you mean "vector subspace"? If so, then your 3 conditions are not quite right. You need to change (3) to "closed under scalar multiplication."

Comment: I think you should take a step back and review what it means for $\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}$ to be a vector space in the first place. What is the zero vector in this space? (Hint: it is a certain $n\times n$ matrix.) What is the scalar multiplication operation in this space? (Hint: it is not matrix multiplication.)

Comment: @user1090793 I don't know. The textbook question is: "Is the set of n × n matrices with det (A) = 1 a subspace of $\mathcal M_{n\times n}$?"

Comment: @user1090793 in an earlier example, the textbook uses it as a vector space of all real matrices of size $n\times n$

Comment: Okay, that's what I assumed, but thought I should check despite the risk of being pedantic.

Comment: @blargoner I found that list of axioms. And, $V$ is a set with $2$ operations: addition and scalar multiplication. So $\det(AB)$ is irrelevant in this case since we're not supposed to be using matrix multiplication? So would I be looking at proving $cA\ne \det(A)=1$?

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking of $\mathcal{M}_{n \times n}$ (with $n$ some fixed positive integer) as a real vector space with the addition operation just being addition of matrices. If $S$ were a subspace of $\mathcal{M}_{n \times n}$, then the following 4 properties would hold for $S$:

1.) It would be a nonempty subset of $\mathcal{M}_{n \times n}$

2.) It would be be closed under addition of matrices.

3.) It would contain the zero vector of $\mathcal{M}_{n \times n}$, which is the zero matrix.

4.) It would be closed under scalar multiplication, i.e., for $A \in S$, $rA \in S$ for any $r \in \mathbb{R}$.

If there is at least one of these properties that $S$ does not satisfy, then $S$ is not a subspace of $\mathcal{M}_{n \times n}$. So, as soon as you've pointed out that $S$ does not contain the zero matrix, you've already answered your question. You could do more work to show that $S$ also fails to satisfy closure under addition, but this would be unnecessary.

Comment: What does it mean to be nonempty? Does it mean the same thing as containing the zero matrix? Also, *if* I were to prove $S$ doesn't satisfy closure under addition how would I do so if I can't add matrices?

Comment: My textbook says $\mathcal{M}_{n \times n}$ forms a vector space under the laws of matrix addition and scalar multiplication. I think I've got things figured out now

Comment: I'm glad to hear it!